# Background job every 1 minute, service, should I call `stopSelf()`?

Tags: android, android-service, alarmmanager, android-pendingintent

I use `AlarmManager` to start service every 1 minute to perform some background job.

Here is code snippet:

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, PostLocationService.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(context, POST_LOCATION_REQUEST_CODE, intent, 0);

    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

    alarmManager.setInexactRepeating(
            AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP,
            SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() + TEN_SECONDS_INTERVAL,
            ONE_MINUTE_INTERVAL, pendingIntent);
```

`PostLocationService` extends `Service`. In `onStartCommand()` I do some job and call `stopSelf()` after this job is done.

But I know that if this service is still running, next time on receiving intent `onStartCommand()` will be executed again and needed job will be done.

What is the best practice here: start new service every 1 minute or keep one service running and waiting for intents?

Comment: I have added my answer , Please let me know if you want more info.

Answer (score 0):

Make Use of [IntentService](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/IntentService.html) for quick background tasks.

> IntentService is a base class for Services that handle asynchronous requests (expressed as Intents) on demand. Clients send requests through startService(Intent) calls; the service is started as needed, handles each Intent in turn using a worker thread, and stops itself when it runs out of work.

Comment: In other words your vote is for stopping service after job's done?